# Best way to access Class property inside a Static method with PHP

Tags: php, oop

Here is my class property

```
private $my_paths = array(
        'imagemagick' => 'E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\ImageMagick',
        'pngcrush' => 'E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\pngCrush\pngcrush.exe',
        'jpegtran' => 'E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\jpegtran\jpegtran.exe',
        'gifsicle' => 'E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\gifsicle\gifsicle.exe',
        'pngquant' => 'E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\pngquant\pngquant.exe',
        'pngout' => 'E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\pngout\pngout.exe'
);
```

There is a static method in the same class...

```
public static function is_image($file_path)
{

    $imagemagick = $this->my_paths['imagemagick']. '\identify';

    echo $imagemagick;
}
```

Of course this gives me errors like

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context...
```

I then tried accessing the property like this `self::my_paths['imagemagick']` but that did not help.

How should I handle this?

Comment: Make them static and `self` will work

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need the `$` sign in front of the variable/property name, so it becomes:

```
self::$my_paths['imagemagick']
```

And `my_paths` is not declared as static. So you need it to be

```
private static $my_paths = array(...);
```

When it does not have the `static` keyword in front of it, it expects to be instantiated in an object.

Comment: That was my problem, missing the `$` when I would try a static property thanks

Answer (score 11):

you cannot access non-static properties in static methods, you either should create an instance of the object in the method or declare the property as static.

Comment: this is the correct answer as the selected answer will throw `PHP Fatal Error : Access to undeclared static property`

Answer (score 3):

make it static property

```
   private static $my_paths = array(
    'imagemagick' => 'E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\ImageMagick',
    'pngcrush' => 'E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\pngCrush\pngcrush.exe',
    'jpegtran' => 'E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\jpegtran\jpegtran.exe',
    'gifsicle' => 'E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\gifsicle\gifsicle.exe',
    'pngquant' => 'E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\pngquant\pngquant.exe',
    'pngout' => 'E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\pngout\pngout.exe'
   );
```

and call it like this

```
   self::$my_paths['pngcrush'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you could make your variable my_path static also.

`self::my_paths['imagemagick']` does not work, because the array is private and could not used in a static context.

Make your variable static and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods in a class can't access the non static properties in the same class.

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object
>   created, the pseudo-variable `$this` is not available inside the
>   method declared as static.

If you wan't to access the properties of the same class then you must define them as a static.

```
Example: 
class A{
    public function __construct(){
        echo "I am Constructor of Class A !!<br>";
    }

    public $testVar = "Testing variable of class A";

    static $myStaticVar = "Static variable of Class A ..!<br>";

    static function myStaticFunction(){

  //Following will generate an Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context 
      echo $this->testVar;

 //Correct way to access the variable..
    echo Self::$myStaticVar;

    }
}

$myObj = new A(); 
A::myStaticFunction();
```